# Background-color and image are not displaying in Edge

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function that, upon execution, needs to open a window and print the innerHTML. The function works smoothly on Firefox; however, on Edge, the barcode and the header background-color:#063d8b are not displayed for some reason. I tried to create elements instead of innerHTML but with no results.

Any help is appreciated.

```
function PrintBadge(personlaid, fullname,funkcija, image) {
var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT',);
mywindow.id = "mywindow"

const words = fullname.split(" ");
let name = words[0];
let surname = words[1];
mywindow.document.write('<html style="font-family:helvetica"><head><title style="text-align:center">' + document.title + '</title>');
mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title + '</h1>');

let beforePrint = document.createElement("div");


beforePrint.innerHTML = `
     <div style="border:1px dashed #333;width:340px;height: 190px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;padding:0.5rem;print-color-adjust: exact;">
        <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;border:1px solid #000;background-image:url('../static/images/bgw.jpg');background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat; background-size: cover; width:340px;height:190px;print-color-adjust: exact;z-index:2000;">
            <div style="background-color:#063d8b;display:flex;flex-direction: row; align-items: center; justify-content: space-around; border-bottom:1px solid #333; border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;height:20px;padding:5px 0px 5px 0px">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;margin-left:20px;color:#FFF;">${personlaid}</h2>
                <h2 style="color:#FFF;">COMPANY</h2>
            </div>
            <div style="display:flex;flex-direction: row;">
                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;padding:5px 0px 0px 5px;">
                    <img src="${image}" style="width:130px;height: 115px; object-fit: cover;border-left:5px solid navy; border-radius:3px 3px 0px 0px"/>
                    <img src="/barcodes/${personlaid}.png" style="width:130px;height: 30px; object-fit: cover;border-left:5px solid navy; border-radius:0px 0px 0px 3px"/>
                </div>

                <div style="display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-content: center;margin-left:2vw;">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:right">Name:</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">${name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:right">Surname:</td>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px">${surname}</td>
                            </tr>
                             <tr>
                                <td style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;text-align:center" colspan="2">${funkcija}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2"><small>Function</small></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 `;

mywindow.document.write(`${beforePrint.innerHTML}`);

mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

mywindow.print();
mywindow.close();

return false;
```

}

Comment: Not sure what the issue with the background color could be, but my guess would be that for the images, it simply isn't able to resolve them to the proper absolute URL somehow (maybe because the "blank" window you opened is somehow missing the "context", of what the URL of the opening document was.) Try and provide full, absolute URLs for these images, and see if that changes things.

Comment: (Or explicitly add a `base` element into the popup, that _sets_ the base URL to use.)

Comment: Try to not `document.write`, as well. There are many caveats with that, although it probably won't be your use, you should try to avoid it.

Comment: I remove the mywindow.document.close();  to not close the window, and it seems ok. However, when I press print the background-color,images are gone. I think it is CSS problem.